# Xterm*selectToClipboard doesn't work when put in Xresources

Tags: terminal, xterm, modx-resources

I have a problem with my Xterm and I can't figure out what is wrong:

I need to enable the option `*selectToClipboard` in my Xterm to be able to copy text in the terminal.

To do so i firstly tried to "manually" start xterm with the option with the following command: `xterm -xrm 'xterm*selectToClipboard: true'` which work very well.

Then to enable the option each time xterm is started I put the following line `xterm*selectToClipboard: true` in my `~/.Xresources`  and I used the command `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` to update the settings but it doesn't work: Xterm starts but the option isn't enabled and I can't copy text from the terminal whereas all the other options in the `Xresources` are enabled and work fine.

Does anyone have an idea of what could cause this problem?

Comment: Can you confirm the merge worked with `xrdb -query`?

Comment: I confirm: the option line `xterm*selecttoclipboard: true` appears in both case (xterm started "manually" or xterm with the option in Xresources)

Answer (score 0):

X resources are *case-sensitive*.  The [xterm manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-VT100-Widget-Resources) documents this as

> **selectToClipboard** (class **SelectToClipboard**)
>
> Tells *xterm* whether to use the PRIMARY or CLIPBOARD for  SELECT
>   tokens  in  the selection mechanism.  The **set-select** action can
>   change this at runtime, allowing the user to work with programs
>   that  handle  only  one  of  these  mechanisms.  The default is
>   "false", which tells it to use PRIMARY.

The feature was added to xterm in [patch #209](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_209) (2006). It is not an optional feature.  So (assuming you have typed the command-line as given), there are a few possibilities to check:

- you *could* be running an older version of xterm.  To check this, run

  xterm -v

> The `-v` version option of xterm will have it print a one-line message showing the patch-level along with the configuration for which it was compiled, e.g.,

```
XTerm(261)
```

- The feature can be set/reset using an escape sequence, as noted in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html):

  CSI ? Pm h
        DEC Private Mode Set (DECSET).
  ...
          Ps = 1 0 4 1  -> Use the CLIPBOARD selection.  (This enables
        the selectToClipboard resource).

> Your shell initialization may have something which sends this sequence.

The `xrdb -query` is one way to check for resource-settings, but it is not infallible.  A better tool would be [`appres`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/appres.1.html), e.g.,

```
appres XTerm
appres UXTerm
```

depending on whether xterm is run with/without the `UXTerm` application defaults.  In contrast to `xrdb`, `appres` shows resource settings after taking into account the "app-defaults" files.  (It does not see resources applied only to an instance of *xterm* such as the `-xrm` option).

tmux has a feature which can interfere with selections (whether to primary or clipboard).  That is called `set-clipboard`, and is commented upon here:

- [Enabling mouse in tmux conflicts with paste in X [duplicate]](https://superuser.com/questions/599497/enabling-mouse-in-tmux-conflicts-with-paste-in-x)
- [Re: iTerm2 support for set-clipboard](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/mailman/message/31275089/)

Comment: My bad I mispelled it in my question but I put it with the capital letters in my `Xresources` (I edited my question). It still doesn't work.
I also tried with both `xterm*` and `XTerm*` since I've seen both on the internet but none of it works properly.

Comment: xterm -v gives me Xterm(278) so the feature must be included.
Actually I understand that something might send an unwanted sequence when xterm starts up but I don't knox how to figure out who could do that. I don't have a .Xinitrc in my home only a .Xresources which doesn't seems to do that.

Comment: If I had something unexplainable like that, I'd just compile xterm with the debug-trace turned on, and see why.

Comment: Actually I figured out that it's Tmux which messes with the selectToClipboard setting. It does the same with rxvt and when I detach from the tmux session the selection to clipboard works fine. 

So i'll have to find why it overrides the settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
just need to add the line bellow in your `/etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm` file

```
*selectToClipboard: true
```

**Long answer:**
If you look at man pages xterm(1):

```
man xterm

FILES
   The actual pathnames given may differ on your system.

...
   /etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm
        the xterm default application resources.

   /etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm-color
        the xterm color application resources.  If your display supports color, use this
                  *customization: -color
        in your .Xdefaults file to automatically use this resource file rather than /etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm.  If you do not do this, xterm uses its compiled-in default resource settings for colors.
...
```

I did not find any reference to a user configuration file to set XTerm application defaults, except for `XTerm-color`, so I don't think it exists.

Comment: Thank you! This should be the accepted answer to many Xterm copy paste questions.